# Concatenate two column values in Oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, select, oracle12c, concatenation

I have two columns.

```
Values     Units

1.0           m
1.0 - 5.0       m
empty       null
10,15,20    Km
```

I wanted to concatenate the values and units.

But if i use the below select i am getting my result as

```
select
      case when unit is null then value
        else CONCAT(cast(value as varchar(100)), unit)
      end as new_value
    from table;

values
1.0 m
1.0 - 5.0 m
empty
10,15,20 km
```

I wanted it to be

```
 Values 
    1.0m
    1.0m - 5.0m
    empty
    10km,15km,20km.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

would you try this code? "table1" is data preparation CTE(common table expression). you can just use the last select statement with **regexp_replace** function. **'(\d+)'** searches for digit group then adds the **unit** for each.

```
with table1("value", Units) as 
( 
select '1.0', 'm' from dual union all 
select '1.0 - 5.0', 'm' from dual union all 
select 'empty',  null from dual union all 
select '10,15,20', 'Km' from dual
) 
select regexp_replace("value",'(\d+\.\d+|\d+)','\1'||units) new_value
from table1;
```

Comment: Ah, **much** smarter & more elegant way than my *monstrous* query.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer. But the table i have given here is just sample. So with table1 for data preparation i can not add all the datas since it would be huge amount of data in my actual table.

Comment: Also there are decimal values in the Value column. So if i have "1.0" then my result is like "1m.0m" instead of "1.0m"

Comment: select regexp_replace("Value",'(\r)','\1'||units) new_value
  from table1. Since \r works for decimal values. But it is just selecting the value column. the units are getting concatenated.

Comment: Hi @newintodev, changed the code above. regexp_replace("value",'(\d+\.\d+|\d+)','\1'||units) should be ok.